# Admin order status only pending accesible

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, orders, order-status

I don't know maybe it is correct behaviour (probably not), but in `Sales` → `Orders` → `Specific Order` in comments history box I have available only `Pending` status. Why is  it so and what/where to change to have the rest of the options?

[image: Order status]

### Update 1

There seems to be statuses assigned to states in Magento. Maybe something is wrong there?

[image]

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the only status assigned to the `new` state is Pending. You need to click the button `Assign Status to State` which will then group them together. Have a look at the answers to your question below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct behavior by default.
You can only change a status of an order to one of the statuses available for the order state.
(Do not confuse order state with order status).
In order to have more available statuses, add your new status from `System->Order statuses`.
Then click on the same page on the button `Assign status to state`, select your new status and the state you want (in your case `New`) and save.
You should see your new status in the dropdown on the order view page.

Comment: I assigned my new status to Processing state but still on order view page I can see only pending. I am sure I would missed something, Assist me plz

Answer (score 2):

You can configure *Order Statuses* via `System` → `Order Statuses`.

The `Pending` status is part of the `new [New]` state. You need to assign statuses to certain states which will then be visible via comment on the order during whichever state it is currently in.